# Android Animate canvas.drawLine

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw a few lines on a `DrawView` which extends `SurfaceView`.
in my `onDraw` method I loop over a list of float arrays and draw lines.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

    synchronized (lines) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (float[] l : lines) {
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawLines(l, paint);
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to animate each of these lines. I've tried to use `ViewAnimator` even though it's only Honeycomb and above but either I don't understand how to use it or it just isn't meant to be used with `canvas.drawLine()`. I've tried to use `paint.setPathEffect` but it doesn't seem to work at all. Anyone have any idea how to do this? I just want each line to take something like 1 second to draw one after the other.

Comment: Have you had any success with this? Care to share?

Comment: @Enke sadly I did not have any luck with this. I actually realised my approach was wrong and really didn't want to go back and change it to be able to animate it. If you would like to animate it, you would need to use something like the stop watch class and break down each line into multiple steps. then on each tick draw just a few pixels *additional* pixels of that line. I hope this helps.